# Laravel - use my custom helper functions in config files

Tags: laravel, config

I have this file config-cache.php in the config folder (config/config-cache.php), but when I use my helpers to get the values from the database, it doesn't work! what should i do Can I get these duration values from dynamic databases?

config-cache.php contents :

```
    'configs' => [
        'default' => [
            'prefix' => '_default_',
            'duration' => '+1 Year',
        ],
        'tiny' => [
            'prefix' => '_tiny_',
            'duration' => '+15 minutes',
        ],
        'short' => [
            'prefix' => '_short_',
            'duration' => '+1 hour',
        ],
        'otp' => [
            'prefix' => '_otp_',
            'duration' => '+2 minutes',
        ],
        'block' => [
            'prefix'   => '_block_',
            'duration' => '+5 minutes',
        ],
        'location' => [
            'prefix'   => '_location_',
            'duration' => '+600 minutes',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create a model to interact with your database table

2- In your controller or service provider, retrieve the configuration values from the database and override the configuration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config as LaravelConfig;

// ...

$configs = Config::all();

foreach ($configs as $config) {
    LaravelConfig::set("config-cache.configs.{$config->name}", [
        'prefix'   => $config->prefix,
        'duration' => $config->duration,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend. No matter what I did, this problem could not be solved. It is working properly now.